# How does a Tesla coil work?

Tags: coil

I've been hearing a lot about Tesla coils recently and about resonance and similar things. I was wondering if someone can describe its method of working and how it can tap into ambient energy to output more power than its input power?

Comment: a simple search for tesla coil and/or overunity should guide you to many links. but i don't expect you to objectively answer this question, since you've announced from the very beginning that you want to "debunk" it.

Comment: There are *objective* reasons for suspecting perpetual machine claims to be bunk, *a priori*, and having a reasonable expectation of being able to show that it is so.

Answer (score 5):

It does no such thing. A Tesla coil is just a resonant transformer with a really large turns ratio. It does not create more power out of thin air.

It works like any transformer, just that here the frequency is chosen such that the transformer has the best efficiency.